# Calculation of coordinates for TikZ annotations in PGFplots axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

I'm trying to do some annotation with `TikZ` in a `PGFplots` axis environment by means of nodes. However, the placement of the nodes is going wrong all the time, see the minimum working example below. How can I fix this? How do I calculate the coordinates for the `TikZ` annotation properly?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xtick={-0.1,0,1,1.1},xmin=-0.1,xmax=1.1,xlabel=$x$,
            ytick={-0.2,0,2,2.2},ymin=-0.2,ymax=2.2,ylabel style={rotate=-90},ylabel=$y$,
            unit vector ratio=2 1 1,
        ]
            \addplot[blue,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot[red,domain=0:1] {2*x};

            % Annotation.
            \coordinate (SW) at (axis cs:-0.1,-0.2); % (S)outh (w)est.
            \coordinate (SE) at (axis cs:1.1,-0.2); % (S)outh (e)ast.
            \coordinate (NE) at (axis cs:1.1,2.2); % (N)orth (e)ast.
            \coordinate (NW) at (axis cs:-0.1,2.2); % (N)orth (w)est.

            \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:1,0);
            \fill[black] (A) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south]{A};

             % ??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???
            \coordinate (B) at ($(SE)+(axis cs:-0.1,0.2)$); % ??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???
            \fill[black] (B) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south east]{B}; % ??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???
             % ??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you keep using `axis cs` coordinate system for `nodes`?

Comment: calc is a tikz library and doesn't know anything about axis coordinate systems of pgfplots. Play around with `xmin` and `ymin` values (with possibly `clip=false` added) and you'll see that B would be dancing around.

Comment: You don't need the `$$` in `($(1,0)$)`, just write `(1,0)`.

Comment: @Ignasi. I believe it doesn't matter, since `axis cs` is the default within the axis environment, according to the `PGFplots` manual. See `4.17 Custom annotations`, `PGFplots` manual Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31). Nonetheless, it is indeed more consistent to use `axis cs` everywhere, so I edited the code ;). Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Alennano. Indeed, but both work. The former is a generalization for the `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`. Just left overs from me playing around with the calculations.

Comment: @percusse Understood, but then how am I supposed to calculate coordinates within a `pgfplots` axis environment?

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question. Your problem is how to calculate coordinates within `pgfplots` and not only positioning nodes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The origin of the canvas area is different from the origin of the plot area.
A plot coordinate pair (-0.1, 0.2) inside the calc expression `($(SE) + (-0.1, 0.2)$)` is transformed to canvas coordinates and added to the canvas coordinates of `SE`. But since the origins do not match, the result is moved by the displacement of the plot origin to the canvas origin.
Actually you want to add "relative" coordinates:

```
($(SE) + (-0.1, 0.2) - (0, 0)$)
```

The following example tries to illustrate this:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xtick={-0.1,0,1,1.1},xmin=-0.1,xmax=1.1,xlabel=$x$,
            ytick={-0.2,0,.5,.7},
            ymin=-0.2,ymax=.7,
            ylabel style={rotate=-90},
            ylabel=$y$,
            unit vector ratio=2 1 1,
        ]
            % \addplot[blue,domain=0:1] {x};
            % \addplot[red,domain=0:1] {2*x};

            % Annotation.
            \coordinate (SW) at (axis cs:-0.1,-0.2); % (S)outh (w)est.
            \coordinate (SE) at (axis cs:1.1,-0.2); % (S)outh (e)ast.
            \coordinate (NE) at (axis cs:1.1,2.2); % (N)orth (e)ast.
            \coordinate (NW) at (axis cs:-0.1,2.2); % (N)orth (w)est.

            \coordinate (A) at ($(1,0)$);
            \fill[black] (A) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south]{A};

            \coordinate (CO) at (0pt, 0pt);% canvas origin
            \coordinate (PO) at (0, 0);% plot origin
            \coordinate (D) at (-0.1, 0.2);% displacement as plot point

            \begin{scope}[
              -{Triangle[]},
              node font=\footnotesize,
              inner sep=.15em,
            ]
              % Show canvas origin
              \draw
               (CO) ++(1em, .4em) node[above right] (tmp) {Canvas origin (CO)}
               (tmp.west) -- (CO);

              % Show plot origin
              \draw
                (PO) ++(1em, .4em) node[above right] (tmp) {Plot origin (PO)}
                (tmp.west) -- (PO);

              % Show displacement as absolute plot point
              \draw
                (D) ++(1em, .4em) node[above right] (tmp) {D}
                (tmp.west) -- (D);

              % Show SE
              \draw
                (SE) ++(-1.5em, .4em) node[above left] (tmp) {SE}
                (tmp.east) -- (SE);

               % Show SE + D
               \draw
                 ($(SE) + (D)$) coordinate (SE_D)
                 ++(-1em, .4em) node[above left] (tmp) {SE + D}
                 (tmp.east) -- (SE_D);

               % Show SE + D - plot origin
               \draw
                 ($(SE) + (D) - (PO)$) coordinate (SE_D_PO)
                 ++(-1em, 0em) node[left] (tmp) {SE + D - PO}
                 (tmp.east) -- (SE_D_PO);

               \draw[red, very thick, <->, >={latex[]}]
                 (CO) -- (D);
               \draw[red, very thick, <->, >={latex[]}]
                 (SE) -- (SE_D);

               \draw[blue, thick, <->, >={latex[]}]
                 (PO) -- (D);
               \draw[blue, thick, <->, >={latex[]}]
                 (SE) -- (SE_D_PO);
            \end{scope}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A more clear notation is using the coordinate system `cs axis direction` as shown in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244507/16967) of esdd.

Comment: From the options `xmin=-0.1,` and `ymin=-0.2,` specified in the `axis` environment, I think the lower left corner of the `TikZ` display is the point `(-0.1, 0.2)`.  From your command `\coordinate (CO) at (0pt, 0pt);` and the display rendered that shows the point `CO` at the lower left corner, it is apparent that the canvas coordinates of a point are different than its axis coordinates.  I guess `pt` can be replaced with `mm` or `cm`.  You also label the lower left corner `SW` in the command `\coordinate (SW) at (axis cs:-0.1,-0.2);`.  I think that you do this for calculations.

Comment: From the option `xmax=1.1` and the command `\coordinate (SE) at (axis cs:1.1,-0.2);`, I think that you are labeling the point in the lower right corner of the `TikZ` display `SE`.  With the command `\coordinate (D) at (-0.1, 0.2);`, you are labeling a point `D` along the left edge of the `TikZ` display - 0.2cm above the x-axis.  Why don't you have to have `\coordinate (D) at (axis cs:-0.1,0.2);`?

Comment: To put the label `SE + D - PO` to the left of the point `(1,0)` in the axis coordinate system using the `calc` package, you issue the command `\draw ($(SE) + (D) - (PO)$) ++(-1em, 0em) node[left] {SE + D - PO} -- ($(SE) + (D) - (PO)$)`.  (By the way, you don't need to have `(tmp)` and `(tmp.east)`.)  Why do you have add `(D)`?  Would you get the same display with `\draw (axis cs:1,0) ++(-1em, 0em) node[left] {SE + D - PO} -- (axis cs:1,0)`?

Comment: @Adelyn In the `axis` environment the axis coordinate system is usually the default, therefore I can drop the explicit specifier `axis cs:` at many places there.

Comment: @Adelyn I need `(tmp)` because I want to start the arrows at `(tmp.east)` or `(tmp.west)` explicitly. The additions with `D` are the point of the illustration.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `axis direction cs`:

```
\coordinate (B) at ($(SE)+(axis direction cs:-0.1,0.2)$);
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xtick={-0.1,0,1,1.1},xmin=-0.1,xmax=1.1,xlabel=$x$,
            ytick={-0.2,0,2,2.2},ymin=-0.2,ymax=2.2,ylabel style={rotate=-90},ylabel=$y$,
            unit vector ratio=2 1 1,
        ]
            \addplot[blue,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot[red,domain=0:1] {2*x};

            % Annotation.
            \coordinate (SW) at (-0.1,-0.2); % (S)outh (w)est.
            \coordinate (SE) at (1.1,-0.2); % (S)outh (e)ast.
            \coordinate (NE) at (1.1,2.2); % (N)orth (e)ast.
            \coordinate (NW) at (-0.1,2.2); % (N)orth (w)est.

            \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
            \fill[black] (A) circle (1pt) node[anchor=south]{A};

             % ??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???
            \coordinate (B) at ($(SE)+(axis direction cs:-0.1,0.2)$);??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???
            \fill[red,fill opacity=.5] (B) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south east]{B}; % ??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???
             % ??? WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING. SHOULD BE THE SAME AS NODE A. ???

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the `PGFplots` manual Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31), it says

'While `axis cs` allows to supply absolute positions, `axis direction cs` supplies directions. It allows to express relative positions, includings lengths and dimensions, by means of axis coordinates.'

I really have no idea what this means, but your solution seems to work :S. Do you understand what the difference between `axis cs` and `axis direction cs` is?

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek explains this in  [his answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244517/43317).