# User defined path leads error when using `to` operator with trigonometric calculation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a path leaving the origin at a sight angle and reaching a desired location. Here is my code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\localDistance{5}
\def\localHeight{3}
\def\sightAngle{atan(\localHeight/\localDistance)}
\draw
    (0,0) to[out=\sightAngle,in=180]
        (\localDistance,\localHeight)  node[right]{Error message rises when I set out=\textbackslash sightAngle}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the following error message

> No shape named atan(3/localDistance is known.

My question is: what am I doing wrong here?

I saw a similar issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246872/positioning-a-node-via-using-tikz-to-calculate-arctan2/246875#246875) but at the same time totally different. I tried those suggestions, but didn't work.

Comment: `localDistance` should perhaps be `\localDistance`?

Comment: Try to use \pgfmathsetmacro insread of \def for defining \sightAngle

Comment: @A.Ellet, yes! I just edited. But the problem remains. Thank you!

Comment: @koleygr thank you! It works! Can you pleas post as answer so I can mark is as the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to get this work properly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\localDistance{5}
\def\localHeight{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\sightAngle{atan(\localHeight/\localDistance)}
\draw
    (0,0) to[out=\sightAngle,in=180]
        (\localDistance,\localHeight)  node[right]{Error message rises when I set out=\textbackslash sightAngle}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```