# \foreach coordinate names in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, loops, coordinates

I have some points defined via

```
\coordinate (A1) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (B1) at (-2,1);
\coordinate (C1) at (0,0);
...
```

And I want to place a little dash at their location. I tied two approaches, but both throw me a bunch of errors

```
\foreach \p in {A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3}{
    \draw[thick] ([yshift=-2pt]\p) -- ([yshift=2pt]\p);
}
```

```
\foreach \p in {A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3}{
    \draw[thick] ($(\p)+(0,1)$) -- ($(\p)+(0,-1)$);
}
```

­

Here is MWE if you want to reproduce the error

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = center,
ymin=-1,
ymax=2,
xmin=-6,
xmax=10,
width=9cm,
clip=false
]

\coordinate (A1) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (B1) at (-2,1);
\coordinate (C1) at (0,0);


\foreach \p in {A1,B1,C1}{
    \draw[thick] ($(\p)+(0,1)$) -- ($(\p)+(0,-1)$);
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Both cases work as expected. Howeve, it is unknown, how you use your code fragments. So, please, be so kind and show us an MWE (in form of small but complete document). which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko I didn't attach MWE, because you literally don't need anything to get the error. I was hoping for someone's knowledge about tikz that would immediately noticed what's wrong. Anyway, I've just added MWE for you.

Comment: Your code fragments haven't any error. Error is their use in your document. But, this is unknown (so far). Now I see, that you not use `tikz` but `pgfplots`. At he later you cant use `\foreach` loops on your way. I wonder, why you use `pgfplots`, wha˙t is purpose of this small lines, etc. They can be replaced wit some mark and defined something like `\addtplot [coordinates only, mark=|] coordinates {(<coordinate 1>) (<coordinate 2>) ... (ycoordinate n>)}

Comment: @antshar: How could anyone have known that you use PGFPlots before your MWE!?? You are waisting peoples time, whenever you deside not to include a MWE.

Comment: @Zarko Don't you get errors when you run the MWE?  In fact, despite not having `tikz` package as far as I know, `pgfplots` includes it, so there should be not any issues with `\foreach`.

Comment: @antshar, you are wrong. See my answer below. Both packages have a lot in common but they are not the same. BTW, your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I I can guess, you looking for the following:

[image]

(desired short lines are emphasized by red color)

`pgfplots` is based on `tikz`, however, all stuff from `tikz` doesn't work stragforward in `\pgfplots`. One of such cases is `\foreach` loop. For details see *Manual for Package PGFPLOTS*, section *8.1 Utility Commands*, page 546.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=9cm,
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-6,    xmax=10,
    ymin=-1,    ymax=2,
    clip=false
            ]
\addplot [only marks, mark options={very thick, color=red, mark=|}] 
    coordinates {(-4,0) (-2,1) (0,0)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `\foreach` in every case inside `axis`. Se the manual p. 546-548. Here you can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = center,
ymin=-1,
ymax=2,
xmin=-6,
xmax=10,
width=9cm,
clip=false
]
\coordinate (A1) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (B1) at (-2,1);
\coordinate (C1) at (0,0);
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {A1,B1,C1}{
\draw[thick] ($(#1)+(0,1)$) -- ($(#1)+(0,-1)$);}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with lines]

Edit:

The calculated coordinate above are wrong.

Doing calc inside `axis` is also not straight forward - see: [Calculation of coordinates for TikZ annotations in PGFplots axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244499/calculation-of-coordinates-for-tikz-annotations-in-pgfplots-axis-environment)

This works:

`\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {A1,B1,C1}{ \draw[thick] ([yshift=-2pt]#1) -- ([yshift=2pt]#1);}`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and a solution to make `foreach` work.